# Get the Name from same table instead of ref(same column as id)

Tags: sql

I have "tbl_students" with  id, name ,referred_by_id

```
id  name   referred_by_id
1   test1  2
2   test2  1
3   test3  1
```

referred_by_id have id value only, 
When I retrieve 2nd record

```
2 test2 1
```

but I want

```
2 test2 1 test1 (refname )
```

How can i do this?

Comment: I do not understand your question. An entity is an object. So if you pass that object to the template, you can of course access all the attributes of it if you have defined getter methods for them. So what exactly is it that you are missing right now? It's probably best to show some code that you have right now.

Comment: True, i want to write a getter method, in that i want to send the "name where id matches".

Comment: How did you configure your entity mapping? I mean you are using Doctrine, aren't you?

Comment: Yes i am using Doctrine. Do we have any other solution to do it.?

Comment: i don't understand your problem neither. you entity is related to another one, so it is normal that you have an id

Comment: Using Doctrine is fine, but without knowing how you configured your entity and its associations, it's impossible to tell you what you need to do.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, the output should be => `1 test1 2 test2`, `2 test2 1 test1` and `3  test3  1 test1`. If this is correct, i would wanna know the DBMS you are using, is it SQL-server?

Comment: I think you need Dynamic Pivot.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am using Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said:

> referred_by_id have id value only, When I retrieve 2nd record
>
> 2 test2 2

But the **second** record in the table you provided, is `2 test2 1`.

Assuming that was a typo, and further you require an output like `2 test2 1 test1 (refname)`. Here is a simple query which might get what you want:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.name AS refname 
FROM tbl_students t1 
JOIN tbl_students t2 
   ON t1.referred_by_id = t2.id
ORDER BY t1.id
```

For [MySQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44f9fd/2).
For [PostgreSQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/410152/1)

If this is not what you were looking for, do tell.